# How to avoid duplicate field name in query result

Tags: ruby, sequel, padrino

I am developing a padrino web application. I have two tables:

- `User` table: Has `id`, `name`, `address` fields
- `Post` table: Has `id`, `user_id`, `content`

If I join them,

```
User.join(:posts, user_id:, :id)
```

they return two fields with the same name `id`:

```
id name address id user_id content
 1 jim   ***     3    1      post1
```

I would like to rename each of these `id`s. I want the result to be:

```
u_id name address p_id user_id content
1   jim  ***     3       1     post1
```

I am using Sequel adapter for postgresql db in padrino project.
In mysql query, it will be like this:

```
select u.id as u_id, 
       u.name, 
       u.address, 
       p.id as p_id, 
       p.user_id as user_id, 
       p.content 
from users u 
  join posts p on u.id = p.user_id
```

what should I do?
What I want is not sql query, but code of ruby language. Thanks.

Comment: That query will work in Postgres just as well. Note that assigning an alias that is the same as the column name is pretty much useless, so `p.user_id as user_id` is exactly the same as `p.user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Dataset#select` to set which columns are being selected:

```
User.from{users.as(:u)}.join(Sequel[:posts].as(:p), user_id: :id).
  select{[u[:id].as(:u_id), u[:name], u[:address],
          p[:id].as(:p_id), p[:user_id].as(:user_id), p[:content]]}
```